# Find the coarsest topology?

Tags: general-topology

Please help me!

Let $X$ be a set and $(Y,\tau)$ be a topological space. Let $f_i : X \longrightarrow Y, (i\in I)$ be a collection of maps. Find the COARSEST topology on $X$ such that all maps $f_i, (i\in I) $ are continuous.

Comment: Well, determine which subsets of $X$ you absolutely need to be open, and work from there.

Comment: Don't you simply want to say that the collection $\{ f_i^{-1}[U]\mid i\in I  \text{ and $U$ open in $Y$}\}$ forms a subbasis for the desired topology?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You know that for each $i\in I$ and $U\in\tau$ the set $f_i^{-1}[U]$ must be open in $X$, so let $$\mathscr{S}=\left\{f_i^{-1}[U]:i\in I\text{ and }U\in\tau\right\}\;;$$ what is the coarsest topology $\tau'$ on $X$ such that $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\tau'$? (This topology $\tau'$ is sometimes called the [*initial topology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) with respect to the family $\{f_i:i\in I\}$ of functions.)

Comment: Thank you.
I choose $\tau' = {\bigcap_{i\in I}\left(\bigcup_{U\in\tau}f_{i}^{-1}\left[U\right]\right)} $
It true???

Comment: @ĐặngPhướcNhật: That’s $$\tau'=\left\{\bigcap_{i\in I}\left(\bigcup_{U\in\tau}f_i^{-1}\left[U\right]\right)\right\}\;.$$ No, that makes $\tau'=\{X\}$. You want the topology generated by $\mathscr{S}$ as a [subbase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase). Start by forming the collection of all intersections of finitely many sets of the form $f_i^{-1}[U]$ with $U\in\tau$, and then take arbitrary unions of these intersections.

Comment: $\tau'=\left\{\bigcup_{U\in \tau}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}f_i^{-1}\left[U\right]\right)\right\} $ ??

Comment: @ĐặngPhướcNhật: Once again you’ve made $\tau'$ a single set. You cannot write it this simply. You’d be well advised to write the definition in two steps, as I described it in my previous comment. Let $$\mathscr{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{F}\text{ is a finite subset of }\mathscr{S}\right\}\;,$$ and then let $$\tau'=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}\;.$$

Comment: OK. I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ĐặngPhướcNhật: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I think $\tau'=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\in\mathscr{B}\right\}\;.$
$\mathscr{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{F}(finite):\mathscr{F}\in \mathscr{S}\right\}\;,$

Answer (score 1):

What sets do we require to be open in $X$ in order for $f_i:X\to Y$ to be continuous? (Hint: use the definition of continuity) Call the collection of those sets $C_i$. Is there at least one topology $S$ on $X$ such that $S\supseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}C_i$? (Hint: what is the finest topology on $X$?) Show that the intersection of all such topologies $S$ is again topology on $X$, and that in fact it is the desired coarsest topology.